# is using namespace to distinguish two different function with the same name considered good or bad

Tags: c++, namespaces

Let me provide an example:

```
namespace mynamespace {
    void myfunc(){
        cout<<"hello";
    }
}

namespace hisnamespace {
    void myfunc(){
        cout<<"hello";
    }
}
```

Is this in anyway helpful or I should just stick to having two different function names?

I tried both ways and could not find a difference.

Comment: This is all up to your personal preferences.

Comment: This is the point of namespaces. I don't think it's desirable, but if `myfunc` is the natural name for both functions then this is acceptable.

Comment: If the rames are too general, a more specific name has the advantage, you will not make mistakes. Otherwise only classes thould have general methods. Just introducing a namesopace for bla #1 and bla #2 will not do. IMHO

Comment: I agree with the above, it is a lot better than not having namespaces.  And it also means you should use the generic guideline of not using `using namespace` in your code.  Specialy not `using namespace mynamespace;` or `using namespace hisnamespace;`

Comment: Consider also, both as intended use and to avoid accidental use: [Argument-dependent name lookup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl)

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be answered without undue opinion, but the answer is that it depends on **context**.

In a library with 20 functions/types, two of which might want the same name, introducing two (more) namespaces with just the **one** function each would be confusing.  If, however, each of the two functions logically belongs to a **set** of functions and types that overlap only in that one name, the namespaces help convey that belonging and allow the client to express preferences between them with `using`.

There might also be technical reasons like where classes are defined for ADL, but again, that’s context.